# Filling regions in tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2)--(0,-2)--(-3.464,0)--(3.464,0)--(0,-2);
\draw (-3.464,0)--(0,2)--(3.464,0);
\node[below left](0,0) {$O$};
\draw [red,thick,domain=30:150] plot ({4*cos(\x)}, {-2+4*sin(\x)});
\draw [red,thick,domain=-150:-30] plot({4*cos(\x)},{2+4*sin(\x)});
\draw[<->] (4.5,-2)--node[right]{4 cm}(4.5,2);
\draw (0,2) -- node[sloped] {$|$} (3.464,0)
(3.464,0) -- node[sloped] {$|$} (0,-2)
(0,-2) -- node[sloped] {$|$} (-3.464,0)
(-3.464,0) -- node[sloped] {$|$} (0,2);
\node[above] at (0,2) {$A$};
\node[below] at (0,-2) {$C$};
\node[left] at (-3.464,0) {$B$};
\node[right] at (3.464,0) {$D$};
\node at (1.5,0.78) {4 cm};
\fill[yellow] (30:4) arc (30:90:4);
\fill[yellow] (90:4) arc (90:150:4);
\fill[yellow] (-30:4) arc (-30:-90:4);
\fill[yellow] (-90:4) arc (-90:-150:4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

I was wondering if there's an easy way to translate the yellow regions I have got so that they fit into my diagram (inside the red arcs). If not, does anyone have suggestions for how to shade the region bounded between the rhombus and the red arcs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against filling some area white. In this case it makes things unnecessarily complicated, and you will regret it if you have a background. You can simplify things quite a bit by naming the coordinates. (`siunitx` are borrowed from Zarko's answer.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={text=black}]
 \draw [red,thick,domain=30:150,fill=yellow] plot ({4*cos(\x)}, {-2+4*sin(\x)})
 coordinate[label=left:$B$] (B)
 -- (0,2) coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A) -- cycle;
 \draw [red,thick,domain=-150:-30,fill=yellow] plot({4*cos(\x)},{2+4*sin(\x)})
 coordinate[label=right:$D$] (D)
  -- (0,-2) coordinate[label=below:$C$] (C)  -- cycle;
 \draw[<->] (4.5,0|-A)--node[right]{\SI{4}{cm}} (4.5,0|-C);
 \draw (B) -- node[sloped] {$|$} (A)
  -- node[sloped] {$|$} node[below=0.2em]  {\SI{4}{cm}} (D)
  -- node[sloped] {$|$} (C)  -- node[sloped] {$|$} cycle;
 \draw (A) -- (C) coordinate[midway,label=below left:$O$] (O) (B) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If i correctly understood your question, than you like to obtain the following image:

[image]

I almost completely rewrote your mwe. first I add TikZ library `quotes`, defined two styles (for red lines with yellow fill) and for edge labels), use `coordinate` with labels to determine coordinates A, B, C and D, and change order of drawing. The first is drawn red lines with yellow fill, than lines with white fill and on the end other lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style = {sloped},
             line/.style = {red,fill=yellow, thick}
                        ]
\draw [line,domain=  30:150] plot ({4*cos(\x)}, {-2+4*sin(\x)});
\draw [line,domain=-150:-30] plot ({4*cos(\x)}, { 2+4*sin(\x)});
%
\coordinate[label=$A$]       (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate[label=below:$C$] (C) at (0,-2);
\coordinate[label= left:$B$] (B) at (-3.464,0);
\coordinate[label=right:$D$] (D) at (3.464,0);
%
\draw[fill=white]
    (A) to ["$|$"] (B)
        to ["$|$"] (C)
        to ["$|$"] (D)
        to ["\vphantom{|}\\$|$\\ \SI{4}{cm}"] cycle;  % <---
%
\draw   (A) -- (C) (B)--(D);
\node[below left](0,0) {$O$};
%
\draw[<->] (4.5,-2) -- node [right] {\SI{4}{cm}} (4.5,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** added is forgotten measure of lines "AD" length.